# Migrate LinkedIn to API v2

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using LinkedIn API `v1`, and saw the announcement:

> All developers need to migrate their apps to our newest APIs and OAuth
>   2.0 by March 1, 2019.

I implemented the new Oauth2 Flow (it's basically the same, only changed the endpoint and the permission `r_basicprofile` to `r_liteprofile`) and it worked and returned the code that I use in the retrieve the access token.

After I get the access token, I make one call to return the user's `firstName`, `lastName` and `id`, and another to get the `email` (before it was only 1 request, but it's ok).

Here I saw that using the `Authorization` header it returned an error that said that I had not informed the access token, but if I put the access token in the paramenter `oauth2_access_token` I can make requests successfully.

In their docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) they don't say where to put the access token, and in the Oauth2 flow docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context) it uses the `Authorization` header with the v1 API. But, in any case, it worked using the parameter in the URL.

### In v1 I'm doing:

After **Oauth2** authorization:

```
URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token={{accessToken}}&format=json
```

After authorization using the **Javascript SDK**:

```
URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
Header: oauth_token={{accessToken}}
```

After authorization using the **Mobile SDK (Android)**:

```
URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
Header: Authorization=Bearer {{accessToken}}
Header: x-li-src=msdk
Header: x-li-format=json
```

It's a bit chaotic, because each one is done in a different way, but I wasn't able to make the `v1` API work in a general way for the 3 cases described above. It worked, nonetheless.

But now, how to get the user data **using the v2 API**?

For now I only achieved it with the Oauth2 Flow:

```
URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(...)&oauth2_access_token={{accessToken}}
```

(From what I saw other people posting, they where using the `Authorization` Header instead of the `oauth2_access_token` parameter, and I wanted to use the header, but was only able to make it work with the parameter. If anyone know how to make it work with the header instead I would be grateful).

In any case, my main question is:

**How to make the migration from `v1` to `v2` and make it work in the same way it is now with `v1`?** (using the token received from the frontend and also from the mobile app and retrieve the user information from that token in the back-end, like in the 3 cases I posted above using the `v1` API, of which I was able to implement only the 1st, using the Oauth2 flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears that the mobile and javascript SDKs have been deprecated. See here: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

> SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.

To the best that I can tell, since the OAuth flow is available in the browser only, you'll now need to kick to web to do auth on mobile.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I skipped that when reading the updates. Do you know if there is some tutorial or example of the login flow with LinkedIn in an Android App? I think the preferable flow in such case is using OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant Flow with PKCE (https://oauth.net/2/pkce/).

Comment: No example tutorial that I have off hand. We're using a webview, set the redirect URI to a page under our domain, and have our app watch for the webview redirecting to that URL -- maybe there's a better way.

Comment: This one working for me : 
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=" + {accessToken}